# Java to Android conversion problems

Tags: java, android, graphics

I have a pretty complex Java (JDK 6) code that needs to be converted so it works on Android. That Java code is intended to work with graphics: thus i have a class that extends JLabel (Swing component), "paintComponent" method reshapes that extended JLabel ("cuts" it to look like a circle) and draws  it on the screen (i know, i know - i might use come "drawCircle" method but i need to extend JLabel because it has some popup menu attached to it).

Now, i have a problem - Android don't seem to have "Graphics" type, "Dimension" type, "Rectangle" type, "paintComponent" method and after all, i have no idea what control should i use to draw those customized JLabels on (in JDK 6, i have used JPanel that was container for those customized JLabels).

Please help! I need some advice on what would be the most painless method for converting given Java logic to Android logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android provides [Graphics](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/index.html) and [2D Graphics](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html), used for drawing.

Have a look at [Shape Drawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ShapeDrawable.html) which should assist you in drawing rectangles. Instead of JLabel use [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html). You will have to spend some time in getting to know Android and redrawing your GUI, but I hope I provided some good starting points.
Also note that depending on complexity of your code, you may not be able to use all your Java code, becase Android doesn't provide full Java version.

Comment: What type should i use instead of "Dimension"? And can i use "Observer-Observable" mechanism in Android?

Comment: yes, you will be able to use java.util.Observer and java.util.Observable in Android. As for Dimension, check DisplayMetrics: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK Android doesn't support Swing, so you're going to have to use equivalent Android UI classes. The android UI classes are not a 1-to-1 match with Swing classes, so sometimes an Android port means you need to do a pretty heavy UI rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

Android do not have JLabel, so you can not use this code.

Instead use TextView . You can declare TextView in xml or in java code

Comment: I know, JLabel is not my main problem. My main problem is how to customize shape of extended TextView and draw it somewhere :)